# Ubuntu Server 20.04 Autoinstall

Tags: automation, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to do an hands-free autoinstallation with the brand new Ubuntu Server 20.04. Apparently, they changed their method from preseeding to the new cloud-init-based autoinstall method. I followed the instructions [on the ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls) and created the two files `user-data` and `meta-data` as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls/QuickStart). After that, i served the files in my internal network by starting a python3 webserver with

```
python3 -m http.server 3003
```

After that, i booted  ubuntu server 20.04 from an usb installation stick. In the grub menu, i' changed the boot entry to the following

```
...
linux   /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud-net s=http://<my-laptop-ip>:3003/ ---
...
```

But when the installer starts, it does not access the config files (the web server access log is empty) and the "normal" server installation starts, where you have to enter everything by hand.

The quick start tutorial on the Ubuntu Wiki page refers explicitly to the installation of a virtual server. Does anyone have any experience with the new installation method and can tell me how to get it to work?

**Edit:**

In the meantime I could verify that the autoinstall process works with the tutorial (setup in a KVM). However, the fact remains that the installation over the network on a real server does not work (no request to the HTTP server to load the configuration). After a manual installation I have checked if the HTTP server is reachable and can confirm this.

What can be the reason that the configurations are not loaded?

Comment: Can the boot entry be configured on the USB itself, so install is unattended ?

Comment: @MihaiRotaru I don't use Ubuntu anymore but Debian as a base, but I think that shouldn't make any difference. With Debian it is definitely possible by giving your menuentry an id in the grub.cfg and setting the default entry as described in https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html.

Comment: cheers, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Soooo I finally managed to get Ubuntu-Autoinstall working, the bug is quite easy to fix: I don't know which "bootloader" qemu uses, but it doesn't really matter. Anyway, the Ubuntu installer uses a GRUB boot loader. In a GRUB bootloader, the semicolon character terminates a command. Unfortunately, the cloud-init syntax uses exactly this symbol to parameterize the installation source: `ds=nocloud-net[;key=val;key=val]`, for example `ds=nocloud-net;s=http://_gateway:3003/`.

**tl;dr**
So, what to do? Just escape the semicolon and everything goes back to the way it's supposed to:

```
...
linux   /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud-net\;s=http://<my-laptop-ip>:3003/ ---
...
```

Comment: Another example: `linux   /casper/vmlinuz ip=dhcp url=http://PATH/TO/YOUR_ISO.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net\;s=http://PATH/TO/YOUR/AUTOINSTALL/DIR/ ---`